# when I run this NPX POD-INSTALL it gives me this COCOAPODS IS NOT SUPPORTED IN THIS PROJECT #ReactNative

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, reactive-cocoa

**Package.json**

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.6.2",
    "expo": "^39.0.3",
    "expo-ads-admob": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-av": "~8.6.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~8.5.0",
    "firebase": "7.9.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "~2.6.1",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "^0.63.3",
    "react-native-appearance": "~0.3.3",
    "react-native-dark-mode": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-hide-show-password-input": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-material-ripple": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-tts": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.41",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.62.13",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This is Package.json of my project in react native. How to install cocoa pods in this project I read somewhere that when using expo dependencies in the project you can't install cocoapods in the project so how to install cocoa pods when using expo dependencies

Comment: you can't work with native with expo. If you want to work with native for ios and android you should eject your project but you will lose expo sdk.

Comment: I am using so much expo dependencies my whole code is based on expo dependencies

Comment: why u need add cocoa ?

Comment: for deploying app in the App Store you need cocoa pods to run your project in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

You just can't install cocoa pods when using expo, that simple. If you need some library from react native community that needs to install cocoa pods, you just can't use it unless expo made its own. You can check if that library is available for expo here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/

Almost everything from react native community has its own expo version if needed.

To install, use `$ expo install <module-name>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use expo bare workflow if you want to add react native librairies which are not included in expo client already.

With Expo bare workflow you can still use expo modules like expo-ad-mobs and even expo client if you have some fail over strategy for your newly added librairies.
https://docs.expo.io/bare/exploring-bare-workflow/

But you will have to build the app yourself, while expo managed workflow lets you use expo cli & infrastructure to build your ipa/apk.
If you just want to build the app and not add any other library, just use expo cli commands like `expo build:ios`